# How to prevent increasing of counter if called from another domain

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've created a simple counter in my website:

> https:\mydomain.com\counter?name=download&link=\dist.zip

The valid database entry should be like this:

```
<Settings Name="download" Value="45" Category="Counter" Id="19379db8-7538-434a-bd06-4b3c1ce56455" />
```

Then I've discovered that the link has been compromised and I got weird counter names in the database like below:

```
<Settings Name="download&amp;link=http://gpu-mining-bitcoin.forexbook.club" Value="1" Category="Counter" Id="19379db8-7538-434a-bd06-4b3c1ce56455" />
<Settings Name="&amp;echo ojnvxb$()\ iligwu\nz^xyu||a #' &amp;echo ojnvxb$()\ iligwu\nz^xyu||a #|&quot; &amp;echo ojnvxb$()\ iligwu\nz^xyu||a #" Value="1" Category="Counter" Id="195ce07f-5ba0-4ba9-b704-4b6c68835710" />
```

As a workaround I've disabled to adding counters if not already registered. In short I've disabled automatic counter entries. However it was a nice ability to create a counter without creating it manually.

I think the counter url has been modified & called from external sites. So I tried to find any referrer info but it was null and I couldn't eliminate/ignore external calls.

Can I do that? Can I block counter links if they clicked/called from other sites or programs by bots? It looks like preventing direct access to images from external sites but I don't want to do anything at IIS level.

Comment: Always assume malicious attacks on any public server. You should filter your user inputs. Why don't you use simple string comparisons? What are the requirements on the input?

Comment: It seems like applying simple validation on counter names (e.g. just alphanumeric, no symbols, sensible max length) would be simpler to achieve.